# iOS MDM Server SSL Certificate not trusted by device

Tags: ios, ssl, mdm

The MDM Server is configured with SSL using self signed certificate.
Installed the web server certificate (self signed) on the iOS device. Still receiving the error "the server certificate for {web server} is invalid " Will mdm web server with self signed certificate work? Or do I need to get the certificate signed from trusted CA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the certificate on the device so that it appears Settings > General > Profiles. You can do this either by emailing the cert to an email account configured on the device or by allowing the certificate to be downloaded via HTTP(S).

Comment: Thanks! That work. Installed the local CA root certificate that signed the SSL certificate on the device. It started working after that.

Comment: Can someone confirm that this is still the case with 10.9.3 and iOS 7.1.1? Thanks.